# How to populate array with characters from another array using math.random in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, math, random, char

I'm trying to populate a new array with four random characters from an array containing seven characters. Is this possible? I can't seem to find the correct way to do it.

This is what I have tried but I get an error,

```
char charactersAllowed[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
char currentCharacters[] = charactersAllowed[ (int) 
(Math.random() * 4) ];
```

error : incompatible types: char cannot be converted to char[ ]

Comment: Which language are you using? It's not clear regarding the tags.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Java.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are accessing a single char in the array.

Get 4 random characters with a simple loop:

```java
char[] currentCharacters = new char[4];
for(int i = 0; i < currentCharacters.length; i++) {
  currentCharacters[i] = charactersAllowed[(int) (Math.random() * 4)];
}
```

Also note that it's better practice to define an array as `Object[] variable` rather than `Object variable[]`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I am correct in saying that I need to put that code in a method if I'm using a for loop. How do I return the values to the currentCharacters array?